# Select List/Drop Down hover jumping with CSS3 Animations in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, html-select, css-animations

Perhaps I should log this as a bug with chrome, but I thought I'd check here to see if there are any solutions to the problem.

I have a simple select list with  an animation on the parent div background using CSS3. When I open the drop down list and move the mouse over different options, the blue bar (the hover), jumps around as I move my mouse around especially on the last item in the list.

HTML:

```
<div id="backgroundContainer">
<select >
<option value="">-- Select a Test Case --</option>
<option value="1">Test1</option>
<option value="2">Test2</option>
<option value="3">Test3</option>
<option value="4">Test4</option>
<option value="5">Test5</option>
<option value="6">Test6</option>
<option value="7">Test7</option>
<option value="8">Test8</option>
</select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#backgroundContainer {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #CCC;
background-image:url("https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png");
color: #fff;
height:500px;
width:100%;
-webkit-animation: moveUpDown 240s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes moveUpDown {
0% {
    background-position-y: 25%;
}
50% {
    background-position-y: 100%;
}
100% {
    background-position-y: 25%;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUpDown {
0% {
    background-position-y: 25%;
}
50% {
    background-position-y: 100%;
}
100% {
    background-position-y: 25%;
}
}
```

I created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfQU5/ that uses the code above.

Please take a look and see if I am doing something wrong or if there are any workarounds. Of course I can just remove the background animation, but still odd that it jumps around regardless.

Thanks,

Comment: I tested this on Chrome Dev channel on Mac and I am not seeing the same issues you are seeing. It seems to be working perfectly how you are wanting it to work.   What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Hey Fernker, I am using Version 26.0.1410.64 m on Windows 8 x64, also able to reproduce on Windows 7 x64. I have not tried it on Mac, and I know it does not happen in IE(9+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike,

Yes, the entire page jumps on Chrome, and in the Chrome dev also, not just the drop down menu. It's not a bug, your markup is wrong. It doesn't jump in IE because IE doesn't understand keyframes, or -webkit-keyframes, yet. That's where the jump is coming from. You have the menu nested inside the  tags, so the menu picks up the jump. I have tested it on the Chrome with and without dev turned on, IE9, FF, and later I'll run IE10, and Opera just to see how they react to this coding, but I'm sure it will be the same.

My questions are:

1. What animation are you try to achieve?
2. Do you want the action to fire from one of the drop down choices?
3. Do you intend to have two documents? One .html and one .css or just drop all the code in the .html and have one file?

I fixed all the code and have it working to what I think you were trying to do, but that's assuming I did what you wanted.

Jason,

Comment: Hey Jason,1) Background scrolling with content on top 2) No 3) Yes, a css file and html file.  But after reading your post, I see what you're saying. I need to not put the select list inside the div, and set the position to absolute on the backgroundDiv and set the z-index. Thanks! Don't know what I was thinkin'! Originally I had the set the background image on the <body> tag, but of course I had the same issue since the body tag encompasses all the content.

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

Here's some code. You can leave the box where it is, just have to follow the [CSS rules](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp) and it's all good.

The CSS3:

```
#backgroundContainer {
   width:100%;
   height:500px;
   position:relative;
   background: #CCCCCC url("https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png") no-repeat;
   animation: myOption 5s infinite linear;
   -webkit-animation: myOption 5s infinite linear; 
     }

@-keyframes mymove
      {
      0%    {background:left:0px; top:0px;}
      25%   {background:left:0px; top:-250px;}
      50%   {background:left:0px; top:500px;}
      75%   {background:left:0px; top:-250px;}
      100%  {background:left:0px; top:0px;}
      }

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove
      {
      0%    {background:left:0px; top:0px;}
      25%   {background:left:0px; top:-250px;}
      50%   {background:left:0px; top:500px;}
      75%   {background:left:0px; top:-250px;}
      100%  {background:left:0px; top:0px;}
      }
```

And here's the html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <!-- <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bgContainer.css" /> 
    </head> -->
      <div id="backgroundContainer">
        <select >
            <option id="select" value="">-- Select a Test Case --</option>
                <option id="ov1" value="1">Test1</option>
                <option id="ov2" value="2">Test2</option>
                <option id="ov3" value="3">Test3</option>
                <option id="ov4" value="4">Test4</option>
                <option id="ov5" value="5">Test5</option>
                <option class="ov6" value="6">Test6</option>
                <option id="ov7" value="7">Test7</option>
                <option id="ov8" value="8">Test8</option>
                <option id="ov9" value="9">Test9</option>
                <option id="ov10" value="10">Test10</option>
        </select>
      </div>  
    </html>

You'll have to reset your timer, and your CSS import link, I didn't want to wait 240s every time I ran it.
```

That code is live here: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JasonDavis34/pen/sobte)

[WebPlatform.org](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css)

[W3C.org](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#w3c_all)

Jason,

Answer (score 0):

it's really bug webkit animation, i think u need use this code

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#backgroundContainer {
position: absolute;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-color: #CCC;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image:url("https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png") ;


border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-animation: moveUpDown 20s infinite linear;
    z-index:6;
}
@keyframes moveUpDown {
    0% {
        background-position-y: 25%;
    }
50% {
        background-position-y: 100%;
    }
100% {
        background-position-y: 25%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUpDown {
0% {
background-position-y: 25%;
}

50% {
        background-position-y: 100%;
    }
100% {
        background-position-y: 25%;
    }
}
.select{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;div style="position:relative; z-index:9;"&gt;
&lt;div id="backgroundContainer"&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class="two"&gt;
&lt;select class="select"&gt;
&lt;option class="one" value=""&gt;-- Select a Test Case --&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option class="one" value="1"&gt;Test1&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option class="one" value="2"&gt;Test2&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option class="one" value="3"&gt;Test3&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option class="one" value="4"&gt;Test4&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;/select&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</html>
</body>
```

also

i try use this:

animation-play-state:paused;

-webkit-animation-play-state:paused; /* Safari and Chrome */

it's not rezone for select element

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to say that I had a similar problem on a client's site-- their select elements' selection highlight was jumping around when you'd try to make a selection, but only on Chrome, and then only in Windows.

I tried for hours to figure it out, including setting the -webkit-animation to none for all select elements, but nothing seemed to work, and I didn't see any animation being set anyway.

Well, long story short, there was an -webkit-animation being set on the entire page (on the html element)!  Once removed, it fixed the problem.

I just wanted to share in case anyone else has a problem like this in the future.